# <select> slide option rather than just being open

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not really sure how to create this behaviour. I am trying to add a slide animation to a `<select>` when it is opened. Is there a proper way to do this either using bootstrap or jquery? I have looked for awhile but can't come up with an answer

example

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>First item</option>
    <option>Second item</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".form-control").on('click', function() {
        $(this).slideToggle();
    };
```

edit: I am  looking for something similar to the Javascript that I have included. I have around 90  boxes implemented and I don't really want to change each individual one by hand. I would rather have a blanket solution that automatically applies to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

It replaces the native SELECT with a custom version that can be fully styled.  You might be able to use some CSS transitions or even apply jQuery's `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` methods to the menu.

UPDATE: here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xfxbufdx/1/

Comment: It would technically work. I am looking for more of a blanket solution for ones that already exist. Something similar to the jquery I included in the question. I should of included that, sorry. I am now.
edit: Sorry after looking at this it might actually be exactly what I need! Let me test it and if it works I will mark it as correct

Comment: you are going to have to use something like this as styling the native select elements is not possible...This will require a small amount of markup changes but will solve your problem.